# Eclipse PDE: Exclude test fragments from required plugins

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-pde

I have an Eclipse RCP application with plugins and associated test fragments. When using the "Add required plugins" functionality in the launch or product configuration, the test fragments get added as well.

Can I avoid this? My plugins don't depend on their fragments, and I'd like to select only the "real" dependencies.

Comment: Check in your workspace which plugin as a dependency to the test plugin (by search the plugin name for example) and remove it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Add Required Plug-ins* will always include fragments. Unfortunately, there is currently no way to control whether fragments are included or not.

You will need to manually de-select the unwanted fragments.

Comment: You may want to file an enhancement request here: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=PDE. Also, if you feel an answer is correct (even though in this case it doesn't solve the problem), please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps to keep the focus on older posts which still don't have answers. –

Comment: Was that enhancement request ever filed? If so, please post the bugzilla link :-)

Comment: @ErickG.Hagstrom I didn't manage to do it yet... but feel free to do so if you'd like :)